# Livestream.com API (mobile/m3u8 stream)

Tags: m3u8, http-live-streaming

Is it possible to take a livestream.com channel like http://livestream.com/accounts/7970204/events/2926299 and get an m3u8 HTTP Live Streaming feed from it?

Comment: It’s bit old thread but you can now use public apis released - https://www.livestreamapis.com/docs/

Answer (score 10):

For livestream.com channels you can use m3u8 link like this

http://api.new.livestream.com/accounts/[account_id]/events/[event_id]/live.m3u8

For your example like this

http://api.new.livestream.com/accounts/7970204/events/2926299/live.m3u8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19985728)

Comment: @J.Win. This is not the typical 'you find the answer here' link. This is an actual example and thus a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source of the event page you linked you'll find a `m3u8_url` and a `secure_m3u8_url` which are the HLS master playlists.

Comment: It looks like you need the keys to view this stream, so basically I can't use it in `<video>` tag or VLC. [m3u8](http://livestream-f.akamaihd.net/i/7970204_2926299_d59572ae_1@190080/master.m3u8?dw=100&__b__=678&hdnea=st=1431056552~exp=1431057452~acl=/i/7970204_2926299_d59572ae_1@190080/*~hmac=ab2ec7ca0e872b711c4f252f581f39c230b255f30d1fb104436f6714bb563eb1)

Comment: Did you copy the entire URL including the arguments after the `?`. The URL is also redirected. I managed to capture it with `ffplay`. If you can't play it directly in HTML5 try to capture it with `ffmpeg` and re-stream it.

Comment: Yeah, so I guess the key expires after 30 mins or so. I would need to rescrape the url?